# Problem with RewriteRule and exclusion on codeigniter app

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx

I'm running into an issue with an `.htaccess` file.

We used to have a main domain ie: `co.example.com` and recently we switched to `www.example.com`. So we added a rewrite rule to redirect `co.example.com/*` to `www.example.com/*`.

The problem is we have a service running on `co.example.com/api/*` that needs to remain active so I added an exclusion to the redirect

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^api/(.*) [NC]
```

But no matter how I change it Apache always performs a 301 redirect to `www.example.com/index.php/api/*`

Which turns into a problem since the service y being called through a POST request and redirection is made on GET.

This is a sample of the `.htaccess` file.

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^api/(.*) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

What might be the problem with this rule? The Apache server is running behind an Nginx proxy, could this be an issue?

I can't change the 3rd party code to point to `www.example.com/api/*` in the short term, so I would need to solve this with `.htaccess` if possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've addressed the most probable cause in my answer. However, the directives you've posted won't - by themselves - trigger a redirect to `/index.php/api/*`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^api/(.*) [NC]
> ```

The value of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable is the full URL-path, which includes the slash prefix, so the regex should be `!^/api/` (the trailing capturing group `(.*)` would seem to be superfluous). This condition would otherwise always be successful.

You could also use the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead, which matches against the URL-path less the slash prefix (in fact, it's less the *directory-prefix*). This would be marginally more efficient since this is processed first and saves an additional condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule !^api/ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Since we are no longer capturing the URL-path from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, we need to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead in the *substitution* string.

You'll need to clear your browser cache before testing. Preferably test with 302 (temporary) redirect first to avoid caching issues.